# Peforming sensitivity anlaysis for a model where input data has different variability

Tags: python, statistics, modeling, salib

I have an excel file containing inputs (2 number i.e., snow density, grain size), and one output (i.e., temperature) collected from a model. I am trying to calculate the sensitivity of the model output to inputs. How to do it in a right way?
The density varies from 250 to 350 (approximately 40% difference between 250 and 350). Whereas grain size varies between 0.0005 to 0.002 which is a 400% difference between the range.

I am using sobol sensitivity analysis with help of SALib package. Please provide some guidance in this regard.